# When creating my discord bot, I kept getting missing intents error so I fixed that and got BitFieldInvalid

Tags: discord, bit-fields

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [console.log('ready')] })


Client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('[bot name]is online!')
});



Client.login('[insert discord key here]');
```

Also this is my first time using stack overflow so this sorry if this goes wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The `intents` field needs to be a [Discord gateway intent.](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)

Since you're just printing something to the console, you don't actually need any intents, but Discord requires one to be passed at least, so you can just do something akin to:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 })
```

Once you actually need to use data fetched from Discord, you will need to change that to use proper intent fields.

As a side note, you should be using `client` and not `Client` after you defined it as such.

Comment: I replaced the second line with that and I am still getting the bitfield invalid error.

Comment: Try what's listed [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file), it might've changed for v14 which I haven't used.